# How To Upload Image on SQLLite Database In Flutter Application

Tags: flutter, sqlite

The argument type 'XFile?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uint8List'. I am facing such a type of error when trying to upload [image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smWy8.png)

Comment: Providing code instead of images of code helps to get much faster recommendations from the community

Comment: put codes in question

Answer (score 0):

readAsBytesSync() is not the input Type that is expected by base64String method. Carefully read the warning so at least you can do some better research for your problem.